# Java оборачивание потоков

Tags: потоки-данных, java

Добрый день
У меня есть метод который записывает поток данные:

```
public static void write(TaskList tasks, OutputStream out)
            throws IOException {
        DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(out);
        int size = tasks.size();
        dataOut.writeInt(size);
        for (Task processed : tasks) {
            String title = processed.getTitle();
            dataOut.writeInt(title.length());
            dataOut.writeBytes(title);
            dataOut.writeBoolean(processed.isActive());
            dataOut.writeInt((int) processed.getRepeatInterval());
            dataOut.writeLong(processed.getStartTime().getTime());
            if (processed.isRepeated())
                dataOut.writeLong(processed.getEndTime().getTime());
        }
    }
```

Возник вопрос, что будет если я сделаю `dataOut.close()`? Закроется ли тот поток, который я оборачивал (`OutputStream out`)? И вообще, стоит ли в такого рода методе закрывать вообще поток?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. При закрытии обертки будет закрыт также и обернутый поток.
2. Но поскольку вы получили в своем методе незакрытый поток `OutputStream` - это не есть правильно возвращать его закрытым, мало ли им может кто-то еще воспользуется. Так что не стоит закрывать `DataOutputStream`. Сборщик мусора все равно сам "убьет" объект.

Answer (score 3):

А в исходники заглянуть? `DataOutputStream` наследник `FilterOutputStream`. См. реализацию метода `close`:

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    try {
        flush();
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
    }
    out.close();
}
```

Видим, что обернутый стрим закрывается.

Стримы нужно закрывать всегда, т.к. они непосредственно связаны с ресурсами ОС (например файловыми дескрипторами), которые нужно освобождать.